# How does Sharepoint+RtWebParts handle timezones?

Tags: sharepoint, timezone

I want to add some OSIsoft RtWebParts to a Sharepoint page. I want these trends to be shown in different timezones for different users. What I'm finding is that they are always shown in EDT.

Ideally, I want a solution for configuring the presented timezone by page or by user.

Comment: Have you tried asking this on OSIsoft's "virtual campus"? http://vcampus.osisoft.com/

Comment: No, but I did talk to some folks at OSI through our paid support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official response from OSIsoft is: **this cannot be done**.

RtWebparts objects *always* use the timezone of the *Sharepoint site* hosting them. Period.

Other than spinning up a new sharepoint site for each timezone you care about, there is one unappealing workaround:

1. Create your display in ProcessBook wherein you configure the time offset as desired
2. Include the ProcessBook PDI file within an RtActiveView web part
3. Repeat for each timezone

You're still stuck with one timezone (set in the SVG) but now at least you can get multiple timezones without multiple servers.

Answer (score 1):

Michael,

I am the product manager at OSIsoft for RtWebParts.

The time zone is controlled by the SharePoint site, not the web server.  One possible workaround it to create a SP site for each time zone that you would like to support.  Unfortunately, you would then face the challenge of maintaining the content for multiple sites.

I would also like to make a correction to the workaround that is described above.  The workaround should use the RtActiveView web part(which uses ProcessBook .pdi files),  not RtGraphic (which uses ProcessBook .svg files).

Thanks,
Tamara